# Swift map() function with an 'if' condition

Tags: swift

Consider:

```
var arr = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
for i in 0..<arr.count {
    if arr[i] == 15 {
        arr[i] = 1
    } else {
        arr[i] = 0
    }
}
print(arr)
```

How can I implement this by using the *map* function?

Comment: 1. Show what have you tried. 2. you example does not make any sense. What makes `15` specific? Is there some other input?

Comment: please express few more.

Comment: Update your question to show how you implemented it with a loop.

Comment: Try this 
let arr = [11,12,13,14,15]

var maped = arr.map { (val) -> Int in
    if val == 15 {
    return 1
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

Comment: `arr = arr.map { $0 == 15 ? 1 : 0 }`

Comment: Thanks @vacawama

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `map()` with an if-condition inside the closure:

```
var arr = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
arr = arr.map { elem in
    if elem == 15 { return 1 } else { return 0 }
}
print(arr) // [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Using the *conditional operator* `?:` and closure shorthand notation `$0`,
this can be simplified to

```
arr = arr.map { $0 == 15 ? 1 : 0 }
```

`map()` calls the closure with each element in turn,
and returns an array with the closure return values.
Inside the closure, `$0` is the current argument, and the return value
is `1` or `0`, depending on the boolean condition.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. I have experienced with objective c and I want to migrate to swift that is why I am little bit confused about map() function but again thank you for giving me crystal clear explanation.